# MMDrawerController with splitview

Tags: ios

i have an app for both iphone and ipad.

a classic master/detail app for iphone and splitview for ipad.

I want to add a slide out menu using MMDrawerController [Github](https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMDrawerController)

I manage to add it for iphone but i d'ont understand how to add it for ipad and to keep the splitview / NavigationController behavior.

Original code :

```
 self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
// Override point for customization after application launch.
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
    MyMasterViewController *masterViewController = [[MyMasterViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyMasterViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];
    self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:masterViewController];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
} else {
    MyMasterViewController *masterViewController = [[MyMasterViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyMasterViewController_iPad" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *masterNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:masterViewController];

    MyDetailViewController *detailViewController = [[MyDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyDetailViewController_iPad" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *detailNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:detailViewController];

    masterViewController.detailViewController = detailViewController;

    self.splitViewController = [[UISplitViewController alloc] init];
    self.splitViewController.delegate = detailViewController;
    self.splitViewController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:masterNavigationController, detailNavigationController, nil];

    self.window.rootViewController = self.splitViewController;
}
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Trying to use MMDrawerControler :

```
UIViewController * leftSideDrawerViewController = [[MMExampleLeftSideDrawerViewController alloc] init];

NSString *strViewMaster = @"MyMasterViewController_iPhone";
 UIViewController * centerViewController = [[MyMasterViewController alloc] initWithNibName:strViewMaster bundle:nil];
// Override point for customization after application launch.
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] != UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
    strViewMaster = @"MyDetailViewController_iPad";
     centerViewController = [[MyDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:strViewMaster bundle:nil];
}

// unused
//UIViewController * rightSideDrawerViewController = [[MMExampleRightSideDrawerViewController alloc] init];

UINavigationController * navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:centerViewController];

MMDrawerController * drawerController = [[MMDrawerController alloc]
                                         initWithCenterViewController:navigationController
                                         leftDrawerViewController:leftSideDrawerViewController];
[drawerController setMaximumRightDrawerWidth:200.0];

[drawerController setOpenDrawerGestureModeMask:MMOpenDrawerGestureModePanningNavigationBar];
[drawerController setCloseDrawerGestureModeMask:MMCloseDrawerGestureModeAll];

[drawerController
 setDrawerVisualStateBlock:^(MMDrawerController *drawerController, MMDrawerSide drawerSide, CGFloat percentVisible) {
     MMDrawerControllerDrawerVisualStateBlock block;
     block = [[MMExampleDrawerVisualStateManager sharedManager]
              drawerVisualStateBlockForDrawerSide:drawerSide];
     if(block){
         block(drawerController, drawerSide, percentVisible);
     }
 }];

//centerViewController.mm_drawerController = drawerController;
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
[self.window setRootViewController:drawerController];
// Override point for customization after application launch.
self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

So, on the ipad, the slide out menu is working, the detailview is loaded but i don't know how to define the masterViewcontroller / navigationcontroller so it does not work..

(sorry, i m a real nood with objective c and ios concept like you can see)

thank you

Answer (score 1):

@picolo

Unfortunately, Apple enforces a UISplitViewController to be the rootViewController of a window, which means you can't place it inside a container view controller. You'll have to write your own similar split view controller implementation in order to drop it in another container view controller.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

MMDrawer Doesn't works with SplitViewController. Try using MFSlideMenu. It works with almost all types of controllers.

here is the link. --> [MFSlideMenu](https://github.com/mikefrederick/MFSideMenu)

Comment: Do you have any ideas with MMDrawerController or MMDrawer for only the Master view? Their Sample come with SplitViewController

Answer (score 0):

The MMDrawerController will not work with a SplitViewController. (as said int the github project description).